# Can only connect to local tmux session through over ssh

Tags: ssh, tmux

So, I have `tmux` session running on my local machine, but I can only connect to it (or see information about it) if I `ssh` back to myself first:

```
% tmux ls
failed to connect to server: Connection refused
% ssh localhost -t tmux ls
Password:
0: 2 windows (created Mon Nov 26 12:47:44 2012) [208x52] (attached)
Connection to localhost closed.
```

This isn't the worst hoop to have to jump through, but why is it happening, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For its client/server communication, *tmux* uses a named socket (in a UID-based subdirectory) under the directory specified by the TMPDIR environment variable. If this environment variable is not set (or it is empty), then *tmux* uses the directory defined by `_PATH_TMP` from `paths.h`; this is often `/tmp`.

*Note*: The following uses of “session” refer to login sessions, not *tmux* sessions.

My guess is that your *ssh* sessions share a common TMPDIR value (possibly not having one at all), while your “normal” sessions use a different TMPDIR value. Since the TMPDIR values are different in your different sessions, a client in one session type can not directly “see” a server started in the other session type (e.g. the client tries using `/var/folders/random/directories/tmux-500/default`, but the server is listening at  `/tmp/tmux-500/default`).

To fix the problem you can simply adjust your TMPDIR to match whatever it normally is in your *ssh* sessions:

```
TMPDIR=$(/usr/bin/ssh localhost -t 'echo $TMPDIR') && export TMPDIR
```

You can determine the path your client is trying to use like this:

```
tmux -L temp start\; info | grep path
```

This will create a evanescent server using a socket named `temp` instead of `default`, and show you the path to the socket it is using.

Answer (score 2):

Tmux manages sockets under <s>/var/run/tmux</s> /tmp/tmux-USERID and each of these sockets has a name attached to it

For example:

```
$ pwd
/tmp/tmux-2037
$ ls
default  foo
$ tmux -L foo ls
0: 1 windows (created Tue Dec  4 13:36:10 2012) [172x52]
$ tmux -L default ls
0: 1 windows (created Tue Nov 20 16:21:14 2012) [188x47]
$ tmux ls
0: 1 windows (created Tue Nov 20 16:21:14 2012) [188x47]
```

Take a look at what you've got under <s>/var/run/tmux</s> /tmp/tmux-USERID and try attaching to some of those sockets by name to see if that's contributing to your problem (running tmux ls is the same as running tmux -L default ls)

---

If all else fails, it may be worth it to fully detach that tmux (close all windows and exit fully) and then rm /tmp/tmux-500/default to see if there's something stateful about your current problem.

Comment: There's no `tmux` directory in `/var/run` for me (I'm using `tmux` 1.6).

Comment: Ack sorry about that, I was looking at an ancient version of tmux.  It seems sockets have migrated to /tmp.

Comment: the only entry in `/tmp/tmux-500/` is `default`, but `tmux -L default ls` still gives me `failed to connect to server: Connection refused`.

Comment: What permissions do you have on the tmux binary and on the /tmp/tmux-500 directory and it's contents?

Comment: the `tmux` bin is 555 (owned by me), `/tmp/tmux-500` is 700 (owned by me), and `/tmp/tmux-500/default` is 770 (owned by me).